# django Warning 302 in post from UpdateView

Tags: python, html, django, forms

"Hello, what I need is to add a record in one model (Historico) and update the status of a record in another model (Factura) in the same form. However, I am getting a 302 error in the console.

> [23/Apr/2023 18:02:40] "POST /facturas/actualizar/1 HTTP/1.1" 302 0

This is my form:

```
class FormActualizarFactura(forms.ModelForm):
    comentario = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Factura
        fields = ('estado', 'etapa', 'email', 'comentario')
```

This is my view:

```
class ActualizarFactura(UpdateView):
    model = Factura
    form_class = FormActualizarFactura
    template_name = 'facturas/fac_actualizar.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('facturas:listaFacturas')
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if super().post(request, *args, **kwargs):
                historico = Historico()
                historico.factura = isinstance(self.object, Factura) and self.object or None
                historico.estado = self.object.estado
                historico.user = request.user
                historico.comentario = request.POST.get('comentario')
                historico.save()
            else:
                # Se produjo un error al actualizar la factura
                messages.error(request, f'Error al actualizar la factura: {self.object.NFactura}')
                
        except Exception as e:
            # Se produjo un error general
            messages.error(request, f'Error general: {e}')
        
        return redirect('facturas:listaFacturas')
```

Can you help me or should I implement another method to have two separate forms (but validated in a single HTML form) and each one perform its function in a TemplateView?"

Update the status of a record in one model and add it to the Historico table, all from the same form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with django, however I do know that HTTP code 302 is not an error. It is simply a redirect. You should check the actual response being sent as it may be containing a `Location: http://example.com` header.

EDIT:

The problem is that you are returning a redirect in the post request. If you are using some kind of client to send the post request and it's not following the Location header, then that's your problem. It appears like everything on your backend is going fine.